# Get number of rows read in Spark thrift server query through Listener

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-thriftserver

I'm trying to build a monitoring system for our ST server.  So far something like logging query, rows retrieved/red and time spent will be fine.

I have implemented a custom Listener, I am able to retrieve query and time without problem, listening for `SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart` and `SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd`

Something like this:

```
  //Structure to hold executionId, query itself from the description and startTime
  val queries = new HashMap[Long, (String, Long)]

def onExecutionStart(event: SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"----------executionId: ${event.executionId}")
    logger.info(s"----------description: ${event.description}")
    logger.info(s"----------startTime: ${event.time}")
    logger.info(s"----------metrics")

    queries.put(event.executionId, (event.description, event.time))
}

def onExecutionEnd(event: SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd): Unit = {
  logger.info("-----onExecutionEnd")
  logger.info(s"---------executionId: ${event.executionId}")
  logger.info(s"---------endTime: ${event.time}")


  val executedPlanMetricsMap = queryExecution.executedPlan.metrics
  printMetrics(executedPlanMetricsMap, "executedPlan")
}

//Help method to print metrics map
def printMetrics[A] (metricsMap: Map[String, A], metricType:String): Unit ={
    try {
      logger.info(s"---------metrics from $metricType with size: ${metricsMap.size}")
      metricsMap.foreach { case (k, v) => logger.info(s"---------------metric from $metricType " +
        s"key: $k, value: $v")}
    } catch {
        case e: Exception => logger.info(s"---------empty $metricType")
      }
  }
```

I'm only printing them on the log so far, just to check if its possible to retrieve the values I need. This one example output

```
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------executionId: 16
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------endTime: 1630665171840
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------query: select *
    from <myDatabase>.<myTable>
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------metrics from executedPlan with size: 6
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------------metric from executedPlan key: numFiles, value: SQLMetric(id: 82, name: Some(number of files read), value: 1)
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------------metric from executedPlan key: pruningTime, value: SQLMetric(id: 85, name: Some(dynamic partition pruning time), value: -1)
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------------metric from executedPlan key: metadataTime, value: SQLMetric(id: 83, name: Some(metadata time), value: 121)
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------------metric from executedPlan key: filesSize, value: SQLMetric(id: 84, name: Some(size of files read), value: 36148)
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------------metric from executedPlan key: numOutputRows, value: SQLMetric(id: 81, name: Some(number of output rows), value: 0)
INFO EventMonitorCustomListener: ---------------metric from executedPlan key: numPartitions, value: SQLMetric(id: 86, name: Some(number of partitions read), value: 1)
```

As you can see, I got the query, the total time spent through the start and end times. But when I check metrics from the executedPlan values are not consistent. numOutputRows is 0 when it should be a number (21 in my example specifically) I also tried with `queryExecution.executedPlan.collectLeaves().head.metrics` as i found [here](https://fossies.org/linux/spark/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetricsSuite.scala) with same result

First question: Is it possible to retrieve the number of output rows from the `SparkListenerSQLExecutionEnd` event?

If not, I'm able to retrieve them from the `SparkListenerStageCompleted` event from the accumulables `stageCompleted.stageInfo.accumulables` with key "internal.metrics.input.recordsRead". But in this case i'm not able to link the stage or the job to the SQLexecution. i.e. I got jobid=4 and stageId=5, executionId=12 but there is no value in any event to link one to another.

Second question: Do you know a way to know which stage or job an execution  belongs to?

Kind Regards

EDIT:

I found a way to link executionId with JobId, through jobStart.executionId. It's working fine in a STS in docker, but not in my real STS. It may be something related to the STS configuration?

Comment: How did you capture the query? I'm looking for something to capture the queries for the spark job but I don't see that part in the code you shared.

Comment: To gather the query you should use SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart

  private def onExecutionStart(event: SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart): Unit = {

    val query = event.description
}

Answer (score 0):

We finally managed to found why my jobStart came without executionId in the properties. It was because the incrementalCollect was set to true. Setting to false fix the issue.