# Get all read/write queries made in spark job using Spark Listener

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, listener

I want to get list of all read/write queries that have been made (using dataset API) in the current spark job. For example,

```
Dataset<Row> readDataFrame = spark.read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", drivingUrl)
            .option("dbtable", "Select * from A where country_code='US'")
            .option("driver", driver)
            .load();
```

I expect to capture the query: `Select * from A where country_code='US'`. I tried using listeners for this so that I can capture this info for any spark-submit job I am running without having to alter the main code itself.

**What I tried**

1. **QueryExecutionListener**

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(String funcName, QueryExecution qe, long durationNs) {
        SparkPlan sparkPlan = qe.executedPlan();
        //Tried to search the methods/properties inside it, but couldn't find anything
    }
```

I tried finding in the SQLMetrics, child spark plans etc, but couldn't get the info I'm searching for.

2. **SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart**

```
@Override
    public void onOtherEvent(SparkListenerEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart) {
            SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart sparkListenerSQLExecutionStart = (SparkListenerSQLExecutionStart) event;
            SparkPlanInfo sparkPlanInfo = sparkListenerSQLExecutionStart.sparkPlanInfo();


            System.out.println(sparkListenerSQLExecutionStart.description());
            System.out.println(sparkListenerSQLExecutionStart.details());
            System.out.println(sparkListenerSQLExecutionStart.physicalPlanDescription());
    }
```

Here also, these details(and other I looked) didn't had the query info I was looking for.

I believe it's possible to capture this info as I have seen projects like [SparkSplineAgent](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline-spark-agent) and questions in StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69045385/get-number-of-rows-read-in-spark-thrift-server-query-through-listener) have it, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lot of trial and error, I finally found a way to do the above. In the listener that implements QueryExecutionListener, I added

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(String funcName, QueryExecution qe, long durationNs) {
    LogicalPlan executedPlan = qe.analyzed();

    //maintain a queue to keep track of plans to process
    Queue<LogicalPlan> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(executedPlan);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        //get the first plan from queue
        LogicalPlan curPlan = queue.remove();

        if (curPlan instanceof LogicalRelation) {
            LogicalRelation logicalRelation = (LogicalRelation) curPlan;
            BaseRelation baseRelation = logicalRelation.relation();

            if (baseRelation instanceof JDBCRelation) {
                JDBCRelation jdbcRelation = (JDBCRelation) baseRelation;
                System.out.println(jdbcRelation.jdbcOptions().table());
            }
            System.out.println(logicalRelation.relation());
           
        }

        //add all child plans to the queue
        Iterator<LogicalPlan> childItr = curPlan.children().iterator();
        while (childItr.hasNext()) {
            LogicalPlan logicalPlan = childItr.next();
            queue.add(logicalPlan);
        }
    }
}
```

This gave me the desired output of

```
SELECT * from A where country_code='US'
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's old, but I might get lucky :) Did you maybe try to associate the table name/SQL query with the metrics available via SparkListener? 
I'd like to connect the [Executor Task Metrics|https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#executor-task-metrics] (especially outputMetrics.RecordsWritten) with the name of the table, that the data is written to, but without any luck as of now.